# XOR A String In PHP With Key Is An Integer

Tags: php, c++, xor

I am making a `HTTP` `POST` request to my server from my `C++` application via `sockets`, I will be `XORing` the `POST` values from my `C++` application before they are sent to my server. Once these `XORed` `POST` values are sent to my server I am going to need to be able to 'decrypt' them before processing the values on my server.

My `C++` application currently is `XORing` `strings` like so

```
char *XOR(char *string)
{
    //key = 0x10
    char buffer[1000] = { 0 };
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(string); i++)
        buffer[i] = string[i] ^ 0x10;
    buffer[strlen(string)] = 0x00;
    return buffer;
    //yes I know, this function could be written much better. But that is not the point of this question...
}
```

Now in `PHP` I am using this function to `XOR` a `string`

```
function XOR($string, $key)
{
    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($string); $i++) 
        $string[$i] = ($string[$i] ^ $key[$i % strlen($key)]);
    return $string;
}
```

I have tried calling it like this

```
$decryptedValue = XOR($_POST['postParam1'], "16");
```

And like this

```
$decryptedValue = XOR($_POST['postParam1'], 16);
```

But the value stored in `$decryptedValue` never matches up with the `XORed` value sent from `C++` application

For example if I `XOR` `"test"` in my `C++` application with key as `0x10` the return value is

```
0x64, 0x75, 0x63, 0x64
```

But If I `XOR` `"test"` on my server the return value is

```
0x45, 0x53, 0x42, 0x42
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert your character to an integer with `ord`, then XOR it with `$key` (not using key as a string), then convert it back to a character with `chr`. Otherwise, it XOR's the string value with a string containing `"16"`, which clearly doesn't achieve the same result.

```
function encrypt($string, $key)
{
    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($string); $i++) 
            $string[$i] = chr(ord($string[$i]) ^ $key);
    return $string;
}
```

(My version of PHP thinks XOR is a keyword, so I renamed the function to encrypt).

To test:

```
encrypt("test", 16);
```